# Blender 2.80 Show Seams, Sharp Edges etc. on 3d viewport

Tags: mesh, uv

I couldn't find where I could toggle on/off to show all sharp edges, UV seams, seams, creases on the model. Using Blender 2.8 Beta. Also, can I see normals on the individual edges, faces or vertex with adjustable sizes like it was in 2.79? I'm still trying to adapt 2.80 so go easy on me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find them all in the Overlays drop down menu :

[image]